# How to open dialog when every validation checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a function to open dialog but I'm not familiar with this sample validation.js because I'm new to addEventListener().(This is from bootstrap examples)

```
(function () {
  'use strict'

  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation')

    Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
        }

        form.classList.add('was-validated')
        //dialogOpen();  <-- this makes dialog open when validation still wrong.
      }, false)
    })
  }, false)
})()
```

I want my page to open a dialog before submission when every validation checked. Where should I write dialogOpen() to make this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function () {
'use strict'

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation')

Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
  form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      event.preventDefault()
      event.stopPropagation()
    } else {
      dialogOpen();  
    }

    form.classList.add('was-validated')
  }, false)
})
 }, false)
})()
```